# Почему не работает Autowired при валидации?

Tags: java, spring-boot, валидация, inversion-of-control

Делаю проверку на уникальность поля.

```
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueValidator.class)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Unique {
    String message();
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

При вызове метода валидатора isValid commandsService - null, хотя в контроллере тот же сервис инициализируется.

```
public class UniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Unique,String> {
    @Autowired
    private CommandsService commandsService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Unique unique) {
        unique.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return !commandsService.isUnique(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Внедрение происходит только в бины, а валидатор создаётся не DI-контейнером.

Comment: Видимо каким то образом это можно настроить, поскольку у меня есть рабочий вариант. Пытаюсь просто сделать по аналогии. Может какие то настройки нужны?

Answer (score 0):

Заработало, когда вместо Entity стал валидировать dto и аннотировал контроллер @Validated
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-list-controller - хорошая статья на эту тему